# Bluetooth connection without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I was looking to find a method to connect two phones using bluetooth without having to first pair them. I am trying to omit the annoying bluetooth pop up request. There is an app on the google store that does this called Bluehood. I wanted to use that style of connection for an app I am building in a totally different niche. You can search for the app on the google store called "Bluehood Social Bluetooth". https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile.bluehood

Comment: Read the [Bluetooth Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). They have to be paired before being connected. I wouldn't want an app that did this...it's a huge security risk. There are ways around it if the device is trusted but they still have to be paired.

Comment: Thanks codeMagic, So what about pairing automatically through my app instead of using the default password key pop up method. Where theres a will theres a way?

Comment: Have you poked through the docs yet to see?

Comment: yes, I have read the bluetooth docs extensively. I didnt find an answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

You may create an insecure bluetooth serial connection between two devices.

**To create a connection:**

Identify the `BluetoothDevice` and call its method `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord`

**To receive a connection:**

Get hold of `BluetoothAdapter` and call the method `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord`

This technique won't require the devices to establish a connection using pairing code. Its available in API level 10 and above.