# Is it possible to transfer text messages through Bluetooth without pairing the device in android? if yes how?

Tags: android, bluetooth, sms, chat, message

I am looking for a answer is it possible to transfer a text message through Bluetooth without paring the device. The message will be a a request to accept the connection with custom message including username, just like friend request of Facebook. If yes, please let me know how?

Comment: Have you read about how bluetooth works, and why isn't it allowing such a thing?

Comment: I think it's impossible.

Comment: is it possible to do it through mac address?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do that using bluetooth insecure serial connection.

Detailed description is available [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945171/android-app-bluetooth-connection-without-pairing).

Comment: yes i think it is possible by creating insecure serial connection... Thanks