# Sharing data between Android devices without internet connection

Tags: android, mobile

My coursework requirement is to build an Android application that lists all available mobile devices within close proximity. None of the devices have access to the internet.

To make things easier, the assumption is that all devices have my application installed.

When user first installs my app, they must define a user name and upload a profile picture.

When they launch my app, it should display the following profile info about other devices nearby:

1. User Name
2. Profile picture

Now, I know this is an open ended question, but I'm totally stumped and need some guidance.

Specifically, I find these points challenging:

1. How to establish communication between devices/my app without internet?
2. How to retrieve other devices' profile picture without having to store everything locally on the device

I did some research and found Wi-Fi Peer to Peer, but not sure if this will be suitable for my use case as I don't have internet access. Bluetooth is another option but I think devices would have to be paired first before exchanging data.

WiFi Peer to Peer:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: Peer to peer WiFi doesn't require an internet connection/access point so sounds like the way to go

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bluetooth connection without pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945171/bluetooth-connection-without-pairing), you can transmit data over Bluetooth without pairing by using `BluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()` (for spamming nearby devices with your profile) and `BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord()` (to receive the spam). As the name implies, you shouldn't use this to transfer sensitive data, but you broadcast your profile anyway, so for this purpose it's OK.

Hope this helps you, comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't aware of the insecure method, though won't this pose security concerns? i.e. can it expose unwanted data/controls?

Comment: As I said in my response (though it apparently wasn't clear): it doesn't create any security hole other than anybody in Bluetooth reach being able to read the data you send. But you send data to all anyway, so it is OK