# Bluetooth connection without pairing (Java)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently developping my first app in java.

This app requires a direct connection with my BL652, which doesn' t accept any kind of pairing option. That being said, I'm stuck with the code below, which still tries to pair with my bluetooth device instead of just connecting. Therefore, I wanted to know what am i supposed to do in order to make a connection that doesnt require pairing.

Thanks in advance for any response.

```
  String mac_address = "DA:72:21:29:0F:F0";
  private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("E54B0002-67F5-479E-8711-B3B99198CE6C");
```

---

```
  lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mac_address);
                //uuids = device.getUuids();

                try {
                    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                    socket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
        });
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking here

Comment: How you are supposed to connect with a bluetooth device without pairing

Comment: Nrf Connect is an app that does this feature

Comment: ah right. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945171/bluetooth-connection-without-pairing

Comment: So i should change this socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID); into socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID); ?